# kafka-console-consumer.sh suspected as performing decoding

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using the kafka-console-consumer.sh OOB script from kafka installation folder.
While trying this script with on a byte input, in which is an Hex code values, I'm having the results as the original values.

i.e.
input: 68656c6c6f20776f726c64
script output is: hello world

I suspect that this OOB script decode hex values.
Anyone can approve/deny that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you update your question to include the CLI/code samples that you're running please

Comment: hi @RobinMoffatt, we have an application that writes to a topic(using rdkafka 0.11) in which it is writing the value as a byte DT. question is, if this script decode avro byte DT when consuming through..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how your application is serialising the data onto the topic.

`kafka-console-consumer.sh` will by default *deserialise* the contents of a message using `StringSerializer`.

You can also use something like `kafkacat` to inspect the contents of messages and deserialise them using various options:

```
 -s key=<serdes>    Deserialize non-NULL keys using <serdes>.
 -s value=<serdes>  Deserialize non-NULL values using <serdes>.
 -s <serdes>        Deserialize non-NULL keys and values using <serdes>.
                    Available deserializers (<serdes>):
                      <pack-str> - A combination of:
                                   <: little-endian,
                                   >: big-endian (recommended),
                                   b: signed 8-bit integer
                                   B: unsigned 8-bit integer
                                   h: signed 16-bit integer
                                   H: unsigned 16-bit integer
                                   i: signed 32-bit integer
                                   I: unsigned 32-bit integer
                                   q: signed 64-bit integer
                                   Q: unsigned 64-bit integer
                                   c: ASCII character
                                   s: remaining data is string
                                   $: match end-of-input (no more bytes remaining or a parse error is raised).
                                      Not including this token skips any
                                      remaining data after the pack-str is
                                      exhausted.
                      avro       - Avro-formatted with schema in Schema-Registry (requires -r)
                    E.g.: -s key=i -s value=avro - key is 32-bit integer, value is Avro.
                      or: -s avro - both key and value are Avro-serialized
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Robin Moffatt - by deserialise you mean, transform the hex to its original value ? i.e. 68656c6c6f20776f726c64 deserialise into 'hello world' ?

Plus, using a different consumer will resolve, and keep the hex value as is if not using the same StringSerializer API ?